# TypeScript group by property with accurate key-value associations

Tags: typescript

I want a group by function where group types are accurately modelled. For example in the following it is clear that `tag.value.format()` should type check because we're working from the `release` group.

```
const tags: ParsedTag[] = [
  { type: 'release', value: Semver.parse('1.2.3')! },
  { type: 'unknown', value: 'foobar' },  
]

const tagGroups = groupByProp(tags, 'type')

// Goal: .format type checks
console.log(tagGroups.release.map(tag => tag.value.format()))
```

My attempts to build such a function can be found in [this TS Playground instance](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=45&ssc=51&pln=45&pc=60#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wMoFMQDctRwBmUEIcA5KjvlBQFD0wCeYWcACslNQCYAqyAOZwAvPThwAPnADecFmwBclAK4A7ANbqIAd3UUA3HFzIANqqwrUMKMHUiAvhOlyFrK5ShYzWNFiMTc0sVbDwCADowgDUCOGcmDzgASXVeLAAPZAAjXwBpLGZ+D3RROBs7B1d1VRBsuJlUZjqIM0ZFdlT0rNysAB5+MTgNbT11AD4hgCUsAGNoXj6K+xEZGrqCABo4fnH2pILmVABZZBhZgAsVvpnZ7cPUSbKAOQh1Z9UzMxzfPpd5ADat0OcHscE0hQgRDgtwAuipbkC5odYXBMjAsGl0A84AB+GHIwpwFTqLC0eIAiHMKEE2aw+h7RJsFJpTI-LAPG5zJ5wB6nc5XBxcu4s7rsw7FNiPRhEDSzGDAN5wISkVRgABCzA4pDAfQA8tkAFZojIYrGitm9e4ms28dBdS35QqofVG8bjAAULgyqBUBsNANhmxcVOeyBAnjy9AAlAi5gtXQG8qj0Zi7Raek6iiU8XB-QDk8S4KTaNt87DJrIXB04NFglgAIIwEFlfOF1Pmh2ZjmFSVYdD4tuoklkgguebqGzlLBYXhDWSOFDoW4JusWRvNwplo2BxmSbwwVRQdRwH0Rby8VSzLAej0qiBqlaobYZaNiSsuSQTqf3tVhiNDBklKFP+WComgtb1k2hyMJIkjANCd6qmAT4Ar+YCgaiojYcMrJEPYs5vlWcFwehqHoZhQyBp+8SwaRyHkchmERGAqioBcHqvnR+5YIex7KgxDioC4jjbNQhH0Ak37wDAwi+pw3B8IIQiBlR-zuMoXg+H41AUNspjrqENCRGAik3hQACMEQAEwRAAzBQ0YAITxMGkjyB0KgUCMOj6HpQSGZQRAQBA2TcBQrmSPQ9L0NJCjCAA4shpQCQ+GpajqHqyUIz6UB0jmwQA9IVcAJRA5gqBEwVQCAZwaewlxzJownfq0WARGYEBCFliXJee2n+BEtVgD1IiiJM2URAZlhVdAtUwB60ZLUAA).

Comment: Please include all of the relevant code in your question, not as a link - and describe specifically what the `groupByProp` function is supposed to do, other than just that it should type-check.

Comment: I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The code in full is:

```
type IndexableKeyTypes = string | number | symbol

type Indexable<T = unknown> = Record<string | number, T>

type JustIndexableTypes<T> = T extends IndexableKeyTypes ? T : never

type KeysMatching<Rec, Keys> = NonNullable<
  {
    [RecKey in keyof Rec]: Rec[RecKey] extends Keys ? RecKey : never
  }[keyof Rec]
>

type GroupBy<T extends Indexable, K extends IndexableKeys<T>> = {
  [KV in JustIndexableTypes<T[K]>]: Array<T extends Record<K, KV> ? T : never>
}

type IndexableKeys<Rec> = KeysMatching<Rec, IndexableKeyTypes>

export function groupByProp<Obj extends Indexable, KeyName extends IndexableKeys<Obj>>(
  xs: Obj[],
  keyName: KeyName
): GroupBy<Obj, KeyName> {
  type KeyValue = JustIndexableTypes<Obj[KeyName]>
  const seed = {} as GroupBy<Obj, KeyName>

  return xs.reduce((groupings, x) => {
    const groupName = x[keyName] as KeyValue

    if (groupings[groupName] === undefined) {
      groupings[groupName] = []
    }

    groupings[groupName].push(
      x as Obj extends Record<KeyName, KeyValue> ? Obj : never
    )

    return groupings
  }, seed)
}

//
// TEST
//

import * as Semver from 'semver'

type ParsedTag =
  | { type: 'unknown'; value: string }
  | { type: 'release'; value: Semver.SemVer }

const tags: ParsedTag[] = [
  { type: 'release', value: Semver.parse('1.2.3')! },
  { type: 'unknown', value: 'foobar' },  
]

const tagGroups = groupByProp(tags, 'type')

 // Goal: .format type checks
console.log(tagGroups.release.map(tag => tag.value.format()))
```

A link a TS Playground instance of this can be found [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=59&pc=62#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwIYCMA2EDSEQAq4EAzlALxQnABOAlnAOZQA+UcArgLboQ2tUQPAPaYAUGNCRYiFBmwAeAhSgc4AazjCA7nAB8KgEoQAxsJoIF1ekwGcefADRQCeiVOgApDtXhI0WBBEkCRKBpTKKMAQiGR+coF4hMRkAPwuUABc7BAAbnzuxFBJJACyqMAmABYMjArGJs4l4VAAcsJwrRyYmPIQCmJQUADeg0NQANoNSVAMUOr4wgBmUA0AutkNU6ZJa1BRMQhkJVDp0-hZOfk0YwC+Ewsgy6uma2JukkUA4jTCHGAAIRASn2yGisRk-j6TVB4KOkIS2BKYRaoyGExwADVZnAoN5fLIAthgqQlBi1noNlAAII0GioYGRMGHMgNcyWHBNTEGdLKbJwPJ8Ny3QrSeJE3D4UINFolcqVGpMeqmZzivpJEkkD4oMDmYBQJZqEzAOgdKCMX7-IEABV+YAUAHl0AArWEshESpr4VqoLjQA4QtWJKWOl16PQACjGyBI2Sdzoma0cY0ePr92SSaYgYgAlNkfn9AcD416QFmDGioB5ivhMahMBxoJR8cAg8SUqGE5nfRAKWMzHBqFQIBAECphrcoKgyAWrcWXaXyxIhjQIMAODRcTGAHSrhAcEwQCMRi2F2okZzIHMUCtjIYDoen-5ZlTIB7ent7ac1kB1hvZu9ZhWE9LTAc8JifMAsz2chYNUWQlgYUdr0rcZzVA8DIOglRE0AkVAMgzDQOg7cwB8KoozQoZkCnMh4zdCE2QsBRuz9Us-0bHkoHo-lBRuNCc2XcZV3XTd0LPJgSDuZwSBHBBBPwgB6RSxGUlwAFEAGUCFUlSxDoLhdRofUACpaKgTSIC4a4DV+LgoAAclk6y+Ac0VoGtVAaFkhACFQZhyDGNhhirYhsgctRNB0OAHIAbigXJ60bbJrFqKARSGYLQsgcLV2wacIDihKkogbJLJcmht3KzE+HSiQH31YB-NjKBPO80c-MYRMcLGEKPFyiB8tkhznES-8yqs65SK82SIwcgBGbcACZtwAZgcnMAEJ0uTIY+rCxzIq0XQRuK8bHKWYRhHQLyHJ2oYxDeMQGqrfzZzAMhKEgm07QjJrGAvRyPA25c1K+YR62ybdLpoLgKmy6BqlMdQpIfUQIG3TBhEYP63tAkhd0GiACu3OGwFxgKDH+7cxsbaHzDh4AIxzFmgA).

The part I was having difficulty at first with (leading to the original question) was:

```
type GroupBy<T extends Indexable, K extends IndexableKeys<T>> = {
  [KV in JustIndexableTypes<T[K]>]: Array<T extends Record<K, KV> ? T : never>
}
```

I realized that by iterating over the keyed-value types I could create a filter expression on `T`.

This solution relies on their being a discriminate property in the union which to me seems reasonable and intuitive.